# How can I return Task<bool> from a Mock method using Xunit and Moq

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have this Repository class

```
    public class ComplaintRepository : IComplaintRepository
    {

        private readonly IAppDbContext _context;
        public ComplaintRepository(IAppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<bool> AddAsync(Complaint complaint, CancellationToken token)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => _context.Complaints.AddAsync(complaint));
            return await SaveAsync(token);
        }

        private async Task<bool> SaveAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (await _context.SaveChangesAsync(token) > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

I want to set up a test for the class using xUnit and Moq. When I mock the behavior of the AddAsync method like so:

```
public class ComplaintRepositoryTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void AddAsync_WithValidComplaint_ShouldReturnTrue()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockContext = new Mock<IAppDbContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(x => x.Complaints.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Complaint>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                       .Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
            mockContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                       .ReturnsAsync(1);

            var complaintRepository = new ComplaintRepository(mockContext.Object);
            var complaint = new Complaint();

            // Act
            var result = await complaintRepository.AddAsync(complaint, CancellationToken.None);

            // Assert
            Assert.True(result);
            mockContext.Verify(x => x.Complaints.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Complaint>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once());
            mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once());
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error for the return type of the AddAsync method.
this is the error I am getting:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<CCMP.Domain.Complaints.Complaint>>'
```

I don't know how to go about it. I have tried all the things I have seen online to no avail.

Comment: `DbContext.AddAsync` [returns a `ValueTask<EntityEntry<TEntity>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-addasync-1(-0-system-threading-cancellationtoken)). You did `.Returns(Task.FromResult(true));`, as if it returns a `Task<bool>`. As you can see, it does not return a `Task<bool>`. Change that line to return a suitable ``ValueTask<EntityEntry<TEntity>>`, rather than a `Task<bool>`

Comment: Side note: you almost never ever want to use `async void`. Only use it when you really know what it means. In your case the test method will be started but the test runner will not wait for it to complete and thus not report any potential test failures. Use `async Task` instead.